# Silverlight: Is there a way to globally change the validation template?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

Is there a way to globally change the validation template? I need to make a couple of minor tweaks to it and I don't want to have to edit every single template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, no there isn't. If you're talking about the red border and the sliding popup around TextBoxes, ComboBoxes, etc. They are coded into each control's own ControlTemplate and not referenced (like a Behavior) from a common source. You'd have to redefine the implicit styles for all used basic control, or write your own validation behavior which is independent of the control (e.g. put a red border around it and write some text too) and attach it to every control you use.